# How to save with backbone.js without specifying which attributes but with a callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'd like to save an altered model to the database (set before). If the save succeeded redirect to another page (as example, could be any other action).

Model.save can have two optional properties. First is a hash of properties, and the second are options (like the success and error callback). http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

```
 somemodel.set({foo: 'bar'});
//lots of other logic and misc steps the user has to do
 somemodel.save(); //on success should go here
```

Since the attributes are already set, I only need the callback.

In the past I did:

```
somemodel.save(somemodel.toJSON(), { 
    success: function() { 
        //other stuff
    }
);
```

or passing the values again to the save method

```
somemodel.save(
    { foo: this.$('input').val()}, 
    { success: function(){}
);
```

I'm looking for a way to clean this up. The documents state, the model will fire a change state if there are new properties. But I'd want to redirect the user anyway (saving on new content or old/unaltered).

this does not exist:

```
somemodel.on('success', function(){});
```

and this, is only for validation:

```
if(somemodel.save()) { //action }
```

also "sync" is the wrong event (since it also works for destroy)

Any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
somemodel.save(
    {}, // or null
    { 
            success: function(){}
    }
);
```

will let you save a model with a specific callback without modifying existing keys.

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h5ncaayu/

To avoid passing the success callback as an option, you can

- use the promise returned by `save` :

  ```
  somemodel.save().then(...youcallback...)
  ```
- or use an event :

  ```
  somemodel.on('sync', ...youcallback...);
  somemodel.save();
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely better than what I had. To bad it still feels a bit dirty (provide a paramaeter, just for the sake of providing an paramater). Maybe I should delve deeper and overwrite/extend Backbone.sync to give back a "success" and "error" event. Weird that it does that by default, since backbone is so much about loosely coupling with events versus callbacks.

Comment: {} and null are not the same in this context. {} means to send an empty object to the server, whereas null means you aren't passing in any object to save(), and that save() should send the attributes of the object.

Comment: @jerzy That's incorrect, please check Backbone doc on `model.save` : a complete representation of the resource is sent  to the server  if you don't pass a `patch: true` option http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save. {} and null will have the same behavior

Comment: I am reading Model.save() documentation, but I don't see where it says that. Better citation?

Comment: Straight from the doc : The attributes hash (as in set) should contain the attributes you'd like to change — keys that aren't mentioned won't be altered — but, a complete representation of the resource will be sent to the server. Or have a look at the Fiddle and see what happens in each case

Answer (score 3):

Backbone.Model has a very convenient method called "changedAttributes" that will return a hash of changed attributes that you can pass to save. So...

```
model.save(
   model.changedAttributes(),
   {
       success : _.bind(function() {...},this), //_.bind() will give scope to current "this"
       error : _.bind(function() {...},this);
   }
);
```

Nice and neat...

Comment: Also nice and definitely will be handy,  but I prefer the other solution better I think (less code). Nice solution with that bind though! I always stored this in another variable so I could access in the success/error callback, but this feels more robust.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this approach won't report changed attributes outside of a change event, so it's possible that changedAttributes() would return false instead of your actual changed attributes.  Just something to keep in mind.